# Unable to start the Video recording on Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to develop an application in which recording should start automatically. As of now, I am able to start recording only when user presses a button, otherwise the code is throwing an exception **java.io.IOException: invalid preview surface**

I have tried delaying the start of recording of video to allow the surface being displayed properly, but still it did not help.

Comment: it would be helpful to see your code. It sounds like you need to wait for the surface to be properly initialized, so I would specifically find it helpful to see how you delayed the start of the recording.